# How do I fix this error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" without altering the quality of my model?

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to train a neural network model while also calculating the training loss of the model. In order to simplify the code, I am generating different parameters in the same "for", but I get a "too many values to unpack (expected 2)" error. Please note my knowledge on python is very limited as I'm just getting started, and this code has been written by a teacher (non of my classmates seem to have gotten this error), I just had to change some lines to get basic parameters and complete the code.

```
epochs = 50
training_loss_per_epoch, test_loss_per_epoch, test_accuracy_per_epoch = [], [], []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    training_loss = 0
    #training_loader
    for data, labels in training_loader:
        predict = model(data.to(device))
        loss = loss_function(labels.to(device), predict)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        training_loss += (loss.item() / len(labels))
    test_loss, correct, total = (0, 0, 0)
    #test_loader
    for data, label in test_loader:
        predict = model(data.to(device))
        loss = loss_function(label.to(device), predict)
        test_loss += loss.item()
        if torch.argmax(predict) == torch.argmax(label):
            correct += 1
        total += 1
    accuracy = correct/total*100
    training_loss_per_epoch.append(training_loss)
    test_loss_per_epoch.append(test_loss)
    test_accuracy_per_epoch.append(accuracy)
    print('training loss: {:.3f}, test loss: {:.3f}, test accuracy: {:.2f}%'.format(training_loss, test_loss, accuracy))
```

The error is in

```
for data, labels in training_loader:
```

and it results on the following:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Note: "labels" is the tensor, and data contains information about heart diseases, but the dataset has already been prepared to work on, since it is a class activity.

I defined my nn with the following code

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        #Capa 1
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(13, 16)
        #Capa 2
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(16, 2)
        pass

    def forward(self, x):
        # Layer 1
        x = self.linear1(x)
        #Activate the 1rst layer
        x = F.relu(x)
        #Layer 2
        x = self.linear2(x)
        #Activate the 2nd layer
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
        #pass
        return x
```

I have done some research, but since my knowledge is still very poor, I haven't been able to solve anything. I have tried to add a `[:2]` next to `training_loader`, or even using `*` in front of data (as of `*data`), but it's to no use.

Comment: Please add how you're setting `training_loader`.

Comment: The error means that the individual elements of `training_loader` are longer than 2, not `training_loader` itself.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a loop? Maybe it should just be a single assignment, `data, labels = training_loader`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your answer, my training loader is defined by the following code `training_loader = DataLoader(X_train, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(X_test, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)`

Comment: @Barmar I am actually not sure about anything, this was a half written activity given to us by a teacher, and this part is the only one he said we do not need to change (he wrote it himself)

Comment: If the code given by the teacher is getting an error, you should talk to the teacher.